# Loop week based on culture info

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, cultureinfo

How do I loop the whole week (monday-sunday) based on culture info, so in my case monday will be the first day of the week? And is it possible to find the `int` value of the day at the same time?

For some information: I need to make this in order to make some generel opening hours for a store.

Comment: What do you mean, you already get `DayOfWeek` with `DateTime` obj

Comment: I need to output some input fields based on the the week day. And it have to start out with Monday

Comment: i didn't get about looping through weeks, Do you have any date range or specific calender week.

Comment: No date range. I need this for making opening hours in a store. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you need is the following loop.

```
        DayOfWeek firstDay = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
        for (int dayIndex = 0; dayIndex < 7; dayIndex++)
        {
            var currentDay = (DayOfWeek) (((int) firstDay + dayIndex) % 7);

            // Output the day
            Console.WriteLine(dayIndex + " " + currentDay);
        }
```

The modulo 7 is important, because the firstdayofweek can vary by different cultures.

Comment: This works very nice and for getting the currentDay to cultureinfo day name I used: System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName(currentDay)

Answer (score 1):

This would give you the first day of the week in a given culture.

```
DayOfWeek firstDay = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
```

this could subsequently be...

```
int firstDay = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
```

DayOfWeek.Sunday = zero

DayOfWeek.Saturday = 6

You would iterate it like any other int.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime Dt = new DateTime(2011,5,13,0,0,0);

int WeeklyOffValue = (int)Dt.DayOfWeek
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/TimePeriod.aspx) includes the class **Week** with support of the culture:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public void WeekDaysSample()
{
  Week week = new Week( new DateTime( 2011, 05, 13 ) );
  foreach ( Day day in week.GetDays() )
  {
    Console.WriteLine( "Day: {0}, DayOfWeek: {1}, Int: {2}", day, day.DayOfWeek, (int)day.DayOfWeek );
    // > Day: Montag; 09.05.2011 | 0.23:59, DayOfWeek: Monday, Int: 1
    // > Day: Dienstag; 10.05.2011 | 0.23:59, DayOfWeek: Tuesday, Int: 2
    // > Day: Mittwoch; 11.05.2011 | 0.23:59, DayOfWeek: Wednesday, Int: 3
    // > Day: Donnerstag; 12.05.2011 | 0.23:59, DayOfWeek: Thursday, Int: 4
    // > Day: Freitag; 13.05.2011 | 0.23:59, DayOfWeek: Friday, Int: 5
    // > Day: Samstag; 14.05.2011 | 0.23:59, DayOfWeek: Saturday, Int: 6
    // > Day: Sonntag; 15.05.2011 | 0.23:59, DayOfWeek: Sunday, Int: 0
  }
} // WeekDaysSample
```

This works even today, Friday the 13th :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
   Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(2014, 6, i).ToString("DDDD", culture));
```

July 1, 2014 - Sunday

Answer (score -1):

I believe you want to loop through the weeks, something like this

```
foreach (DayOfWeek dy in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)))
{
     dy.ToString() // this would be Sunday, monday ......
}
```

Comment: How to I get monday to be the first day? :-)

Comment: @meep I am afraid that won't be possible here as this is an Enum

Comment: @meep Hope someone comes with a better solution else you will have to make your custom list with these values monday ..sunday